# jQuery - Polar Chart customization

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone please help me create a Polar Chart, just like this one below?

http://codex-themes.com/codeus/pages-and-blog/welcome-to-trias-full-width/

Then look at the "OUR SKILLS, STRENGTHS & SCOPES" side

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I want to copy the polar chart on that page, but I just cant do it.. I want to create the same diagram, displaying my skills in HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, etc.. Thanks

Comment: The irony is strong in that comment :-) Anyway, no one here will write anything for you without seeing any effort on your side. You should start with checking their code, seeing what plugin they are using for that data visualization, browse Google for documentation on that plugin, experiment with that plugin and if you still have problems, post your code here.